# change validate message in data annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, entity, data-annotations

my object has field with data type int. when i put in html form in this textbox letter not number the validator say- The field must be a number. how can i change this messages like this

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите название")]
    [DisplayName("Название")]
    public int age { get; set; }
```

Comment: Any reason why this question has been downvoted? Please leave a comment when downvoting a question. IMHO it is a good question.

Comment: Not everyone understand Russian. attribute text should be in English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found a *clean* way to achieve this using Data Annotations. One way would be to write a custom model binder but this seems like a lot of work to do for such a simple task.

Another way to achieve this is to add an `App_GlobalResources` folder to your ASP.NET application. Add a resource file called `Messages.resx` containing a `PropertyValueRequired` string resource.

```
PropertyValueRequired = "Some custom error message"
```

In your `Application_Start` register the resource class key:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "Messages";
}
```

Note that ASP.NET MVC 2 uses the `PropertyValueInvalid`  instead of `PropertyValueRequired` resource key.

IMO using Data Annotations to perform validation logic is limited (maybe in .NET 4 this will change). If you want to have full control over the validation logic I would recommend you using a validation library such as [Fluent Validation](http://www.codeplex.com/FluentValidation) or [xVal](http://xval.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I have had exactly the same problem. I also moved from data annotations to Fluent Validation. I find fluent Validation really useful , and easy to customize.

Comment: Any reasons why you recommend Fluentvalidation? Is it better than Enterprise Library Validation application block?  BTW, xVal is currently deprecated.

Comment: I recommend FV because it is lightweight, allows to express complex validation rules in an elegant way, it provides an API for easily unit testing those validation rules and has a great integration with ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and worked around it by specifying a RegularExpression that only allows positive natural numbers.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите название")]
[DisplayName("Название")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Поле возраст не является числом")]
public int age { get; set; }
```

Not sure if there are any downfalls to this solution. It seems to work fine for me.

PS: If you don't want to allow leading zeroes use `"^[1-9]+[0-9]*$"`.

In retrospect: I have to admit though it's a bit weird to add a regular expression to an integer.