# ASP.Net MVC 2 Model Validation Regex Validator fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation, model-validation

I have following property in my Model Metadata class:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Spent On is required")]
[RegularExpression(@"[0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/20[12][0-9]", 
   ErrorMessage = "Please enter date in mm/dd/yyyy format")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayName("Spent On")]
public DateTime SpentOn { get; set; }
```

But whenever I call `ModelState.IsValid` it always returns false because regex is not validating. I have matched the entered date (08/29/2010) against new regex using same pattern and it matches perfectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because regex applies to strings and not `DateTime` properties. If the user enters an invalid string which cannot be parsed to a `DateTime` instance from the model binder it will add a generic error message before your regex pattern executes.

You have a couple of possibilities:

1. [Customize the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439939/change-validate-message-in-data-annotation/2441722#2441722) in a resource file
2. Write a custom model binder
3. Use a string property (I feel guilty for proposing this :-))

Comment: aha, @Darin it is converting `DateTime` to `String` and that is not giving it `MM/dd/yyyy` thanks dear! I'll develop new `ValidationAttribute`, because there are some other validation also needed on this field.

Answer (score 4):

Actualy there is another workaround for this. You can simply subclass the RegularExpressionAttribute

```
public class DateFormatValidatorAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute {
    public DateFormatValidatorAttribute()
        : base(@"[0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/20[12][0-9]") 
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Please enter date in mm/dd/yyyy format";
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value) {
            return true;
        }
}
```

in your Global.asax.cs on application start register the RegularExpression addapter for client side validation like so:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
            typeof(DateFormatValidatorAttribute), 
                typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
```

Now you get to have the build-in MVC regular exression validator client side and keep the DateTime as your property type