# What is the regular expression format for date dd-mm-yyyy?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

What is regular expression format for date dd-mm-yyyy.Following is the code i used but its not working.

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Activation date is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Activation date")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])[- / .]([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2])[- / .](1[9][0-9][0-9]|2[0][0-9][0-9])$", ErrorMessage = "Enter proper date")]
```

Comment: Isn't there pre-built validation method? You can validate the format, but not the date logic with regex.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594496/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation-regex-validator-fails

Answer (score 0):

It would be very difficult to validate a date via regex. For instance, given `29-02-yyyy`, how would you check if the given year is a leap year?

A better alternative would be to programatically use a validator.  Check out how to use one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/939852/453314).

Another approach would be to use the [DateTime.TryParse method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx).  You can easily check the returned boolean value to see if you have a valid date or not.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

```
^(((((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))-((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])))|((31-((0[13578])|(1[02])))|((29|30)-((0[1,3-9])|(1[0-2])))))-((20[0-9][0-9]))|(29-02-20(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))))$
```