# MVC 4 date validation regular expression

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new with MVC 4, also I'm new with .net.
I tried this to validate date (didn't work):

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public string Bdate { get; set; }
```

i did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594496/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation-regex-validator-fails).

i need regular expression works for 1900s and 2000s(for all dates )

please help me.(please regular expression answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Range(typeof(DateTime),"1-Jan-1940","1-Jan-2000")]
public string Bdate { get; set; }
```